# why this insertion sort algorithm is giving me address of the values?

Tags: insertion-sort

This the insertion sort algorithm which I have tried on my own. But I'm stuck , as
This algorithm  is not giving me the correct results instead giving me address of the values.

```
void insertion_sort(int a[] , int size){

 int i,j,temp;
 for(i=1;i<size;i++){
   temp= a[i];
  for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--){
    if(temp<a[j]) {
      a[j+1]=a[j];
    }
  }
  a[j+1]=temp;
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve], as this algorithms "gives" you nothing by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are not assigning the value of `j` outside of the inner loop before using it to assign `temp` to the correct index, I think.

Here's the corrected code:

```
void insertion_sort(int a[], int size) {
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        temp = a[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && a[j] > temp; j--) {
            a[j+1] = a[j];
        }
        a[j+1] = temp;
    }
}
```

In this corrected code, we check that `j` is greater than or equal to zero and that `a[j]` is greater than temp before we move the values in the array to make space for the temp value. After the inner loop finishes, `j` will be one index to the left of where temp should be inserted, so we assign temp to `a[j+1]`.